# Bash completion for user without access to /etc

Tags: bash, autocomplete, non-root-user, chrome-os

I'm using a Chromebook (with a developer mode enabled), and as someone of you may know, there is no write access to the system directories (including `/etc/`).

I'd like to enable the bash-completion option for the local user without adding any files to `/etc`, while I have an write access to `/home` and `/use/local` directories only.

How can I enable bash-completion in this case?

Thank you.

PS. ChromeOS is Gentoo-based, this information might be useful for someone.

Comment: Is "bash completion" the same thing as tab completion in this usage?

Comment: @Wildcard, yes, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash-completion is enabled by sourcing a shell script—it sits at `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` on my Debian box, for example—but you can put it wherever. It looks in its own directory for the completions to load.

Completions used to go in `/etc/bash_completion.d`, but that's now a backwards compatibility directory and can be changed by setting `$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR` before sourcing the script.

You should be able to grab it from [its home on Github](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) and install it to `/usr/local` or `$HOME`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [~/.bash_completion.d/](https://serverfault.com/a/831184) and this [addendum](https://serverfault.com/a/915618)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, bash completion has been disabled in ChromeOS and there is no way to enable it.

See [Chromium Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256907)

Comment: It's deliberately excluded from the build, but that doesn't mean that users can't install it by themselves.